# "Cannot handle hot-plugged CPUs" - implementation question

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm using gRPC library and have lot of "Cannot handle hot-plugged CPUs" logs. I'm confused because condition (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_linux.cc#L74) for this log compares actual CPU on which the calling thread is running with the number of processors the operating system has configured. Why are they doing this? Is this the correct way to detect hot-plugged cpu?

```cpp
if (static_cast<unsigned>(cpu) >= gpr_cpu_num_cores()) {
    gpr_log(GPR_ERROR, "Cannot handle hot-plugged CPUs");
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why are they doing this?

is a difficult question to answer properly. Now

> Is this the correct way to detect hot-plugged cpu?

is easy - it's not, but the goal of the function is not that. The overall code is written with the assumption that the number of CPUs doesn't change during runtime, this simplistic test merely informs you that that assumption is being violated. (and resets the number returned to zero, possibly to not bust out of some array indexed by CPU number?)

I expect your next question is likely to be

> Why do they assume constant CPU count?

Probably because it was much easier to implement and noone contributed an improved version that would not have this limitation? You are free to make one... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to achieve is avoid large number of logs in stdout. I've meant that it logs it because cpu id is greater than configured number of cpu, and it's not consequence of using hot-plugged cpu, but cpu id which not start counting from 0 (host is divided into several logical cpus pool). Now this function returns 1 in this case and doesn't affect app (except lots of unwanted logs in stdout). I wonder what would happen if it start to return real number of cpu instead.

Comment: @ŁukaszJędryczka ok, so the assumption that is being violated is "number of active CPU will always be lower than the total CPU count". It's getting the number of CPUs from sysconf, which is presumably lying and the active CPU from sched_getcpu, which is not. So what would you like to know? Can you make your own version of grpc where you would silence this check? (anything tracked per-cpu will be inaccurate, possibly some statistics)

Comment: Or if you cannot compile your own grpc you could `LD_PRELOAD` your own version of `sched_getcpu` that would remap the CPU numbers somehow.

Comment: Yes we could remap LD_PRELOAD but I would like to know first what would be the consequences if this start to return value > 1. It's hard to analyze whole code, and If you know, it would be very helpful. For example grpc will start to generate 10 times more threads or something on host with 100 cpus...

Comment: @wookieJ my source is analysing the same code, but a quick search reveals that `gpr_cpu_num_cores` is used for determining the default size of some threadpools, you might not want to mess with that

Comment: On the other hand `gpr_cpu_current_cpu` should be fairly safe to change, given the note (value is advisory only) at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/support/cpu.h#L35 ; the main thing that cares about `gpr_cpu_current_cpu` is [channelz](https://grpc.io/blog/a_short_introduction_to_channelz/)